# Run a GitHub project on google Colabratory

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I have a question, there is a GitHub project about **text to speech with deep-learning** but i can't neither run it on local machine nor google colaboratory,

can anyone help on how to run it? as i downloaded the files but it has many files i dont know how to run it.

**it's git hub link==>**

https://github.com/AlisterTA/Persian-text-to-speech

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there is an option to import an .ipynb file from Google Colab. I think it went something like `File > Open notebook > GitHub`. You will have to authorize Colab to access GitHub.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please tag appropriately; this is actually not a question about `tensorflow`, `deep-learning`, or`text-to-speech` (tags edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add these 4 lines at the beginning.

```
!npx degit AlisterTA/Persian-text-to-speech -f
%tensorflow_version 1.x
!wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/48wy3kw4e512ax7/logs.rar
!unrar x logs.rar
```

What are these?

- Load code from github, so you can import hp, model_graph
- Select tensorflow 1.x (the new default is 2.x)
- Download the pretrained model and unzip it.

Now the code can run correctly and generate speech.

Comment: Dear Korakot, Thanks alot for your response to my question,i do all you said and import them, and solved former problem, but it has an error more after i run cell one it says AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'.........................Can help me about this on how solve this problem? thanks so much –

Comment: You need to run `%tensorflow_version 1.x` first. Don't run it after other cells. You may need to restart it all.

Comment: I used this two lines + your modification===> !pip uninstall tensorflow -y
!pip install  tensorflow==1.14 and then reset the notebook and it works nice now. thanks very very much for your modification on code it prepare required files so fast and easy, it works uniqe now. thanks so much, be happy and successful

Comment: You don't need to `!pip uninstall` or reinstall it. TF 1.15 is already install. You just need `%tersorflow_version 1.x`. Or `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf; tf.disable_v2_behavior()`

Comment: yeah, i try it again and it works now and dont need two other lines for install and uninstall, first time i think i didnt reset the notebook thats why did not work well at first time. thanks a lot for your helpful answers. be happy and successful.

Comment: Dear Korakot, I wanna to retrain the   train.ipynb notebook with my own data base, but it did not explain how can i prepare my own data base for retrain text to speech, can help me on how do it? best regards

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use colab to open .ipynb notebooks and experiment with it. Now in your case suppose you want to open demo.ipynb notebook, Follow the below steps:

- change the url https://github.com/AlisterTA/Persian-text-to-speech to https://colab.research.google.com/github/AlisterTA/Persian-text-to-speech and choose demo.ipynb.
- Now run the first cell and most probably you will get an error and this error is because demo.ipynb has some dependency which is not there in colab but available in github.
- So to remove error clone the whole project from github by this command `!git clone https://github.com/AlisterTA/Persian-text-to-speech.git` and sometimes you need to run `!pip install <module name>` so as to install the required module from [pip](https://pypi.org/).

**Note:** Sometimes projects from [github](https://github.com/) are not well documented for example there will be no requirements.txt. If that's the case you will have a difficult time in running the whole project in google colab. You have to manually install modules using pip command as mentioned above and sometimes you may need to change the version of pip as well.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response to my question,i do all you said and import them, and solved former problem, but it has an error more after i run cell one it says   
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'.........................Can help me about this on how solve this problem?  thanks so much